# How to subset the data frame based on selected variable with limited column?

Tags: r, subset

i would like to subset limited column and selected variable as i have multiple column in my data frame.

my sample data:

`df <- data.frame('ID'=c('A','B','C'),'YEAR'=c('2020','2020','2020'),'MONTH'=c('1','1','1'),'DAY'=c('16','16','16'),'HOUR'=c('15','15','15'),'VALUE1'=c(1,2,3))`

i would like to subset ID'='C' and column name 'VALUE1'
Expected output:-

```
  ID VALUE1
1  C      3
```

Appreciate any help...!

What i have tried so far is.

```
df1 <- subset(df,df$ID=='C')
df2 <- subset(df1,select=c('ID','VALUE1')
```

Is there any efficient way to do that as creating multiple data frame when we have multiple is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dplyr chaining function too,

```
df %>% select(ID,VALUE1) %>% filter(ID=="C")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can have both `subset` and `select`

```
subset(df, subset = ID=='C', select = c('ID', 'VALUE1'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Got it ```subset(df, subset = ID=='C', select = c('ID','VALUE1'))``` Great...!